# How to use IComparable to compare complex objects

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class with firstName and lastName. And I want to compare the object based on firstName so I wrote a snippet like below:

```
public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(Customer other)
    {
        return this.FName.CompareTo(other.FName); .
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
 List<Customer> listCustomers = new List<Customer>();
        listCustomers.Add(customer1);
        listCustomers.Add(customer2);
        listCustomers.Add(customer3);

 listCustomers.Sort();
```

It works fine but suppose somewhere I also need to compare based on last name. What can I don in the scenario. I mean I can Always write my own custom methods but is there any other way? Just like I did it for FName can I also use `Icomparable` interface to implement sorting based on LName too.

**Question**: Can I have two version of `CompareTo`

I want something like

```
public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public int CompareTo(Customer other)
        {
            return this.FName.CompareTo(other.FName); .
        }

   public int CompareTo(Customer other)
        {
            return this.LName.CompareTo(other.LName); .
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just have two methods? One that checks first name, and one that checks last name? Or are you wanting a conditional that checks against first name **or** last name?

Comment: It is just a symbolic representation. I am just trying to learn. I mean then I should never use CompareTo. because it provides serious constraint.

Comment: I So whenever I have a single type of comparision in complex type then only I CompareTo is valid and helpful

Comment: If I can have a situation where I need to compare on multiple stuffs then there is no use to CompareTo? Please guide me

Comment: Check the other overloads of the `Sort` method, they let you specify comparison methods explicitly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort

Comment: I just added an edit of what I was trying  to acheive ( Kind  Of).

Comment: As you seem to be realising, `IComparable` and `IComparable(Of T)` are only useful if there is one way to compare values/objects or at least a logical default way. If you want to be able to compare your type in multiple ways then one option is to define one or more copmpanion classes that implement `IComparer` and `IComparer(Of T)`. In such classes you can implement multiple comparison methods, either one per class or multiple determined by, for instance, a constructor parameter. Otherwise, just use ad hoc `Comparison(Of T)` delegates or the like.

Comment: Not sure why a negative vote.  But I understood what @jmcilhinney is trying to convey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works fine but suppose somewhere I also need to compare based on last name. What can I don in the scenario.

In that scenario, you can use one of [the overloads of `Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is [an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zSmFiZ) that compares in three different ways.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer> 
        {
            new Customer("a", "c", "b"),
            new Customer("b", "a", "c"),
            new Customer("c", "b", "a"),
        };

        // A: uses Customer.CompareTo(...)
        customers.Sort();

        // B: uses a lambda
        customers.Sort((x, y) => x.Last.CompareTo(y.Last));

        // C: uses MiddleNameComparer.Compare(...)
        customers.Sort(new MiddleNameComparer());
    }
}
```

Here is the `Customer` class that implements `IComparable`.

```
public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    public Customer(string first, string middle, string last)
    {
        First = first;
        Middle = middle;
        Last = last;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Customer p)
    {
        return this.First.CompareTo(p.First);
    }
}
```

Here is the `MiddleNameComparer` class that implements `IComparer`.

```
public class MiddleNameComparer : IComparer<Customer>
{
    public int Compare(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        return x.Middle.CompareTo(y.Middle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So either I can create my own class and implement `Icomparer<>` or even better use lamda :)

Comment: @Unbreakable Yes. If I would start with a lambda. Later, if I found myself copy/pasting the lambda all over the place, I would encapsulate it into my own class that implements an `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: This example uses a Lambda to create a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate.  That delegate has the same signature as the `IComparable(Of T).CompareTo` method and the `IComparer(Of T).Compare` method. They are three ways of doing the same thing, with one built into the type being compared, one being implemented in helper classes and one being ad hoc. Building it into the type is best if that type gets compared a lot, a helper class is best if the type gets compared regularly but there's no single obvious way to compare and ad hoc is better for one-off comparisons.

Comment: I see. so eventually it is pointing to the same CompareTo method, just like an explicit delegate would.

Comment: No, not the same `CompareTo` method.  In this case, the ad hoc method is using the `CompareTo` method of the `String` class. When you get down to it, comparisons are almost always going to be on parts of a complex type that are `Strings`, numbers or a similar simple type so you can almost always use the `CompareTo` methods of those types in your complex comparison.

Comment: I see what you are saying. So all these are just wrapper.